# Enum vs Dictionary usage in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, enums

I am working on an abstract class called "GenericReceiver" containing an enum called "Status." It contains failure codes for the receivers as follows:

```
public enum Status
    {
        Fault1 = 0x0,                  // 00
        Fault2 = 0x201,                // 513
        //etc
```

These fault codes are not standardized across the receivers (although some are shared), so I cannot make the entire enum a member of the abstract class. However there are quite a few fault codes and I'd like to reduce code duplication as much as possible.

I considered using a dictionary instead and inheriting the shared fault codes. I would then add the remaining fault codes. The problem that arises is that the fault codes should not be able to be changed at runtime, hence the original enum implementation.

Is there any way to concatenate two enums or convert a dictionary to an enum?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: You could just choose not to change the dictionary. It doesn't matter whether it's possible or not, if you don't do it then it doesn't happen.

Comment: @harold If there's ever anyone else going to be touching your code, you can't count on that.

Comment: @krillgar then they could also change the enum (they could even just refactor it into the dictionary approach everywhere). You can't defend against people changing the code.

Comment: @harold You can alter the definition of an Enum only by changing the declaration. However, with a regular Dictionary, you can call the Add or Remove method whenever you want during execution time.

Comment: @krillgar yes but you are assuming a thread model where the attacker changes your code. Of course if someone else touches the code maliciously, they can just make it do whatever, no matter what you initially wrote.

Comment: @harold It doesn't even have to be malicious. It could be another collaborator not realizing that they shouldn't change a dictionary. Maybe they need one extra setting for their code.

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative.  Although you cannot derive enums, you can simply repeat the name in your derived classes and begin by setting all the values to be the same as in your base class.  For example:

```
public abstract class GenericReceiver
{
    public enum Status
    {
        Fault1 = 0x0,
        Fault2 = 0x201
    }
}
public class DerivedReceiver
{
    public enum Status
    {
        Fault1 = GenericReceiver.Status.Fault1,
        Fault2 = GenericReceiver.Status.Fault2,
        Fault3 = 0x302
    }
}
```

This has the advantage of being a compile-time solution, but requires you to have some mechanism for testing that the derived classes enums always implement all the values in the abstract base class enum (Unit Test??), just in case you add codes later to the abstract class.  Although you will probably not like it on code duplication grounds, I thought I'd suggest it anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Enums must be created at compile time. You can't alter them after that.

Your best bet would be to implement a [`ReadOnlyDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712875(v=vs.110).aspx). Of course, you can't change those after creation, so your inheritance would be a little complicated.

Here's how I would do it:

```
public abstract BaseCodes
{
    protected ReadOnlyDictionary<int, string> CommonCodes = new ReadOnlyDictionary<int, string>
    {
        {0, "Fault1"},
        {513, "Fault2"}
    };
}

public class DerivedCodes1 : BaseCodes
{
    public DerivedCodes1() 
    {
        // Get a writable copy of the common codes
        var codes = CommonCodes.ToDictionary();
        codes.Add(404, "Not Found");
        codes.Add(42, "Life, the Universe, and Everything");

        Codes = new ReadOnlyDictionary<int, string>(codes);            
    }

    public ReadOnlyDictionary<int, string> Codes;
}
```

This isn't the cleanest in the world, but since you can't inherit from enums, this would give you the best answer for your question.